# Is there a way to show more columns per row from FastF1 (see code)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab

I am very new to coding and I'm trying to view data from FastF1. I am attempting to do this using Python and Jupyter Lab. Whenever I print two columns using the code below:

```
import fastf1
from fastf1 import plotting
import pandas as pd

plotting.setup_mpl()

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

fp3 = fastf1.get_session(2022,'Monza','FP3')fp3.load()
fp3_laps = fp3.laps
fp3_d1 = fp3_laps.loc[fp3_laps['Driver']=='VER']
print([[fp3_d1.LapTime,  fp3_d1.LapNumber]])
```

[image]

My aim would be to get have both the `LapTime` and `LapNumber` columns next to each other.

Comment: does this work?  `print(fp3_d1[['LapTime', 'LapNumber']])`

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! Is the difference here that I select the columns seperately, and you select two columns from the same dataframe (effectively at the same time)?

Comment: I've posted the explanation in an answer below, please have a look, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fp3 = fastf1.get_session(2022,'Monza','FP3')fp3.load()
fp3_laps = fp3.laps
fp3_d1 = fp3_laps.loc[fp3_laps['Driver']=='VER']
print([[fp3_d1.LapTime,  fp3_d1.LapNumber]])
```

From the above code, it looks like `fp3_d1` is a dataframe. So `fp3_d1.LapTime` is a pandas series, in other words, selecting a column from the dataframe. It's the same as  `fp3_d1['LapTime']` (I prefer this notation). You can check with `type(fp3_d1['LapTime'])` to get "pandas.core.series.Series".

And `fp3_d1.LapNumber` (the same as `fp3_d1['LapNumber']`) is another pandas series. The last line of the code is simply to stack 2 pandas series vertically, becoming "a list of 1 list of 2 items", notice the double square brackets `[[` in front and behind `]]` and a comma `,` in between.

The syntax `df[['col1', 'col2']]` is to extract 2 columns from the dataframe, forming a subset of the full dataframe with only the columns `col1` and `col2` side by side. You can check with `df[['col1', 'col2']]` to get "pandas.core.frame.DataFrame".

Your aim to get both `LapTime` and `LapNumber` columns next to each other, is to get a subset of the dataframe with these columns. So the code should be:

```
print(fp3_d1[['LapTime', 'LapNumber']])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do dataframe subsetting like `fp3_d1[['LapTime', 'LapNumber']]`. This will output a subset of the dataframe with the 2 columns indicated.

Refer to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) for more details